# "Duplicate entry '' for key" in Grails Database Migration using hasOne

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-2.0, database-migration

Using Grails [Database Migration Plugin 1.4](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) I want have the following structure of my existing database:

```
class StickerGroup {
}
```

Now I added the class Company and updated the class StickerGroup:

```
class StickerGroup {

   static constraints = { company nullable: true, unique: true }
   static belongsTo = [company: Company]
}

class Company {
  static hasOne = [stickerGroup: StickerGroup]
}
```

I created the migration file and then I perform `grails dbm-update`. After that I get the following error log:

```
2015-01-20 15:03:49,549 [main] ERROR liquibase  - Change Set 2015-01-20-update-Company.groovy::1421762562430-2::mg (generated) failed.  Error: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE `sticker_group` ADD `company_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE: Duplicate entry '' for key 'company_id'
Message: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE `sticker_group` ADD `company_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE: Duplicate entry '' for key 'company_id'
    Line | Method
->>   62 | execute           in liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    104 | execute           in     ''
|   1091 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase
|   1075 | executeStatements in     ''
|    317 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet
|     27 | visit             in liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor
|     58 | run . . . . . . . in liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator
|    114 | update            in liquibase.Liquibase
|     26 | doCall . . . . .  in DbmUpdate$_run_closure1_closure2
|     59 | doCall            in _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2_closure11
|    133 | executeInSession  in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils
|     51 | doCall            in _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2
^     25 | doCall . . . . .  in DbmUpdate$_run_closure1
Caused by MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'company_id'
->>  377 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    360 | getInstance       in     ''
|    971 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|   3887 | checkErrorPacket  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   3823 | checkErrorPacket  in     ''
|   2435 | sendCommand       in     ''
|   2582 | sqlQueryDirect .  in     ''
|   2526 | execSQL           in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2484 | execSQL . . . . . in     ''
|    848 | execute           in com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl
|    742 | execute . . . . . in     ''
|     92 | doInStatement     in liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1ExecuteStatementCallback
|     55 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor
|    104 | execute           in     ''
|   1091 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase
|   1075 | executeStatements in     ''
|    317 | execute . . . . . in liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet
|     27 | visit             in liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor
|     58 | run . . . . . . . in liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator
|    114 | update            in liquibase.Liquibase
|     26 | doCall . . . . .  in DbmUpdate$_run_closure1_closure2
|     59 | doCall            in _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2_closure11
|    133 | executeInSession  in grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils
|     51 | doCall            in _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2
^     25 | doCall . . . . .  in DbmUpdate$_run_closure1
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set 2015-01-20-update-Company.groovy::1421762562430-2::mg (generated):
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE `sticker_group` ADD `company_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE: Duplicate entry '' for key 'company_id':
          Caused By: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE `sticker_group` ADD `company_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE: Duplicate entry '' for key 'company_id':
          Caused By: Duplicate entry '' for key 'company_id'
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:347)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:27)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:58)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:114)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(DbmUpdate:26)
    at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2_closure11.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:59)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:133)
    at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:51)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmUpdate:25)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE `sticker_group` ADD `company_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE: Duplicate entry '' for key 'company_id'
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:62)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:104)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.execute(AbstractDatabase.java:1091)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractDatabase.java:1075)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:317)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key 'company_id'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:848)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:742)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:92)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    ... 12 more
```

**How can I fix this error?**

Comment: Sounds as if your data is not in a valid state, e.g. you have multiple entries with a null company.

Comment: above code is most likely wrong.  there are two StickerGroup and no Company

Comment: @cfrick Sorry, I fixed the code above.Any idea what is missing here?

Comment: You have two StickerGroup entries, neither of which have a company. That violates the unique constraint. If your intent is to allow multiple entries when there is no company then you need to implement your own method of checking unique. If not, then make your migration apply just the new column, then update the data to reflect what it should be, then add the unique constraint.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I don't get your point. I have only one StickerGroup and updated the existing StickerGroup table while creating a new table Company.